# How to get pixel data from SoftwareBitmap in UWP C#?

Tags: uwp

Hi I am developing screen sharing utility in UWP C# project. I have implemented all code at below link.

Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture

Now problem is How can I get pixel data from captured frame. I can convert captured frame in below two object.

1. SoftwareBitmap
2. CanvasBitmap

so How can I get pixel data from these object?

Do I need to perform encode or decode or both operation before to get pixel data?

Comment: `CanvasBitmap` has `GetPixelBytes()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can get a CanvasBitmap instance by calling [CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_CreateFromDirect3D11Surface.htm) method. Calling the [GetPixelBytes](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_GetPixelBytes.htm) method on this instance returns the pixel data of the bitmap as a byte array.

```
using (var frame = _framePool.TryGetNextFrame())  {
  using (var canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(_canvasDevice, frame.Surface)) {
      bytes[] pixelData = canvasBitmap.GetPixelBytes();
  }
}
```

> Do I need to perform encode or decode or both operation before to get
>   pixel data?

The returned data should be in the same pixel format which you specify when you create the frame pool:

```
_framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.Create( 
    _canvasDevice, // D3D device 
    DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, // Pixel format 
    2, // Number of frames 
    _item.Size); // Size of the buffers
```

Comment: Thanks for comment and code and I did all things but I need pixel data in BGR format not it in B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized. How can I convert this pixcel? canvasBitmap.GetPixelBytes() provide bytes of array and if I use that bytes of array then it render/show grabage image. You can show it look by this URL https://ibb.co/0XtZypb

Comment: @JohnSmith You can pass a different format from the [DirectXPixelFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.directx.directxpixelformat) enumeration to get the  data in that format. If the format you want is not there, you might need to convert the data manually (pixel by pixel) to the desired format which might be slow.